# Error with Java

Tags: java

Need some help here. I always get this error:

```
ERROR! THREAD NAME: New I/O  worker #2
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.rs.game.player.content.DungeoneeringShop.open(DungeoneeringShop.java:12)
    at com.rs.game.player.dialogues.DungTutor.run(DungTutor.java:36)
    at com.rs.game.player.DialogueManager.continueDialogue(DialogueManager.java:31)
    at com.rs.net.decoders.WorldPacketsDecoder.processPackets(WorldPacketsDecoder.java:1130)
    at com.rs.net.decoders.WorldPacketsDecoder.decode(WorldPacketsDecoder.java:268)
    at com.rs.net.ServerChannelHandler.messageReceived(ServerChannelHandler.java:98)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:95)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:563)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:558)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:91)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.processSelectedKeys(AbstractNioWorker.java:373)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:247)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:35)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:102)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my class:

```
package com.rs.game.player.content;

import com.rs.game.player.Player;

public class DungeoneeringShop {

    private static final int INTERFACE_ID = 72;
    public static Player player;

    public static void open() {
        for(int i = 69; i < 73; i++) 
            player.getPackets().sendHideIComponent(INTERFACE_ID, i, false);
        player.getInterfaceManager().sendInterface(INTERFACE_ID);
    }
}
```

Comment: if you call open(), make sure player is initialized...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to instantiate your variable `player`. In your example `player` is `null`.
For example if you have a parameterless constructor:

```
public static Player player = new Player();
```

Comment: @user2229998 you're welcome. please accept a answer as right answer to help others who read this question :-)

Answer (score 4):

You haven't initilized `player`. So it is `null`.

It's like

```
null.getPackets()  --------------> NullPointerException
```

So resolution is initialize it before using like

```
public static Player player = new Player(); // at declaration level
```

or

```
player = new Player(); // or later some where before using.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate

```
public static Player player;
```

before accessing it.

Answer (score 1):

Because you haven't initialized player object yet. It should be :

```
package com.rs.game.player.content;

import com.rs.game.player.Player;

public class DungeoneeringShop {

private static final int INTERFACE_ID = 72;
public static Player player;

public static void open() {
    player = new Player(); // or some other constructor of this class
    for(int i = 69; i < 73; i++) 
        player.getPackets().sendHideIComponent(INTERFACE_ID, i, false);
        player.getInterfaceManager().sendInterface(INTERFACE_ID);
    }
}
```

I think you're a new comer to Java World. And you are learning from game development ebook. You should learn base Java more, before came to this.

Hope this help :)

Comment: Well ye I am basically a new comer. Thanks for hepling me! :D